# Run Solana Light/Thin Node on Personal Machine

Tags: solana

Is it possible to run a solana light/thin client on a personal machine (<8 cores) to get access to the RPC API?

The docs make it clear that it's possible to run a full node, but this does not work for connecting to mainnet-beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing, there's no full validator node that can run on a smaller machine against mainnet-beta. There are high requirements in order to keep up with the throughput with the network.

You can run a local test validator with `solana-test-validator` to try out the rpcs locally. But nothing to match mainnet-beta with a small machine today.